# How to give a load priority to external javascript

Tags: javascript, pagespeed, load-time

As title says I want to give a priority to my layer ad which is third party script.Because of delay it has I want to give it priority. I thought I could just put it in in beginning of the body tag, but than it doesn't work properly(shows up under my content). What can I do to give it priority or to make that script loads faster note that I can't modify the script I just have link to it?
Only thing I have is this which is placed above .

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/script.php?s=2501"></script>`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by it "showing up" under your content? Scripts are not visible to the user - only HTML content they might make. The best you can do is have this script be the first to load, and ensure that your own content appears in the correct relative position. You can't improve example.com's connection speed.

Comment: i would use defer or async attributes on the script tag so that my page didn't have to wait on it, since your own code doesn't need it.

Comment: Katana314 by that I literally mean showing up under content i.e it show under banners, images navigation...
dandavis I need it to open before my main content loads